# SQL SELECT Statement max id

Tags: sql

I have a table called apps with id, type, and group_id.
The table has multiple group_id with same number.
I need to get the max id for each group_id number where type equals 1.

My sql skills are not so good.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select group_id, max(id) as max_id
from apps
where type = 1
group by group_id
```